# How can I make file parsing and I/O faster in python when working with huge files (20GB+)

Tags: python, parsing, file-io, bigdata, python-multiprocessing

This is the basic sample code im following:

```
def process(line):
    data = line.split("-|-")
    print(userpass)
    try:
        data1, data2 = data[2], data[3]
        finalline = f"{data1} some text here {data2}\n"
        with open("parsed.txt", 'a', encoding="utf-8") as wf:
            wf.write(finalline)
    except:
        pass

with open("file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        process(line)
```

This is working just fine. But is there any way I could make it run faster using multiple threads or cores??

Or somehow be able to achieve the read and write speed of my SSD while doing the operation?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function calls incur significant overhead in Python. Don't call a function on every line of the file, but inline the definition. Also, don't repeatedly open the same output file; open it once and leave it open.

```
with open("file.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f, \
     open("parsed.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as outh:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split("-|-")
        try:
            print(f"{data[2]} some text here {data[3]}", file=outh)
        except Exception:
            pass
```